# Change UITableView background per section

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that consists of 3 sections. I'd like to apply a background colour to each section.

I have a scenario in which a section may have no cells, or the last cells may not fill the remainder of the view. I'd like to apply a colour in that case.

Comment: share screenshot

Comment: If you don't have many cells, use a stack view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the background per section. I'm afraid that's just now how a `UITableView` works. You can change the background of the whole table, but that is it.

If you want to change the background of a section with no cells, I would suggest perhaps returning a cell with the required background and making it fill the section.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color for the cells in the section:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"YOUR_CELL") as! UITableViewCell
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        case 1:
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        case 2:
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        default:
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
        return cell
    }
```

But if the cell is empty you will have to return an empty cell that only displays the backgroundColor.

There is no dedicated function where you can specify the backGroundColor per section.